# Использование Scanner в java

Tags: java

Хочу одновременно считывать данные из двух файлов и сразу же сравнивать их таким вот образом. Допустим, в файле 1 у меня вот что: 1 3 5, в файле два у меня: 2 1 3. Я сначала считываю 2 из второго файла, потом считываю 1 из первого файла - сравниваю; потом считываю 3 из первого файла - сравниваю с той же двойкой, считываю 5 из первого файла - сравниваю с той же двойкой. Потом я считываю 1 из второго файла и как мне потом считать 1 из первого файла?

Comment: загрузить данные из 1, стравить с 2, зачем усложнять себе алгоритм?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать любое (ограниченное памятью Java-машины) количество объектов типа `Scanner` и использовать их в любом порядке.

Comment: Стоит лишь добавить, что Scanner - далеко не самый быстрый способ работы с файлами. Лучше использовать BufferedReader, если конечно файлы не превышают размера оперативы.